# How to round this number with toLocaleString() method?

Tags: javascript, html, string, function, object

I have this number: 7.425000000000001

And I want to round it like this result: **7,42€**

But my result is 7,43€

This is my code:

```
 this.article.price_pvp.toLocaleString('de-DE', 
       {
            style: 'currency', 
            currency: 'EUR',
            maximumFractionDigits: 2 
        }); //this return me 7,43
```

Comment: Maybe you could do a `yourNumber.toFixed(2)` before using `toLocaleString()` as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tofixed)

Comment: According to what rule? What value is `7.429` supposed to be rounded to?

Comment: @luk2302 I think he just wants to truncate his number to 2 decimals

Comment: @luk2302 I don't think it's meant to be rounded, just decimal places removed.

Comment: I did not ask you @Nenri or JackBashford, I ask OP what *he* wants to do, I can make assumptions about his intentions all day.

Comment: Interesting, I use `Intl.NumberFormat`, wonder if there is any difference

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can change the value of n according to the precision needed. Then you can use toLocaleString

```js
var a=7.425000000000001
var n=2;
console.log(a.toFixed(n)-(1/Math.pow(10,n))*(n-1))
```

Comment: @Jaykant Why wouldn't it ? just put the result of this into your formatter

Comment: Your second method is literally same as the other answer of this question

Comment: No problem, your main solution is good and more mathly, so both could be accepted

Comment: return Math.floor(a * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. I think you need to parse that float value to 2 digits after decimal point.

`this.article.parseFloat(price_pvp).toFixed(2).toLocaleString('de-DE', 
   {
        style: 'currency', 
        currency: 'EUR',
        maximumFractionDigits: 2 
    });`

Comment: not working 'cause of bad decimal handling by js. Look at the other answers for working solutions

Comment: Try this example:  `var a = 7.425000000000001;
var value = parseFloat(a).toFixed(2);
console.log(value);`

Comment: not working for same reason. It returns 7.43 when OP wants 7.42

Answer (score 2):

It's rounding because of the `5` - use `toFixed(2)` first:

```
this.article.price_pvp.toFixed(2).toLocaleString('de-DE', 
   {
        style: 'currency', 
        currency: 'EUR',
        maximumFractionDigits: 2 
    });
```

## EDIT

Change it to a float, then string, then take the first five digits and use `toFixed()`:

```
parseFloat(parseFloat(this.article.price_pvp).toString.substring(0, 5)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: No problem @Nenri always glad to help

Comment: @AntonioMorales `parseFloat(7.425000000000001.toString().substr(0,5)).toFixed(2);` That's a bad-looking solution, but working. (should i make it an answer ?)

Comment: @JackBashford You forgot to parse it again into a float before using `.toFixed(2)`

Comment: Whoops @Nenri fixed now

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with [roundingMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#roundingmode) option

```
this.article.price_pvp.toLocaleString('de-DE', 
  {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR',
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    roundingMode: 'floor'
  });
```